# Laravel DatabaseTruncation exceptTables still truncated

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a laravel project with a Dusk setup.

From the docs, to keep the database clean for tests, we should use `DatabaseTruncation` trait.

In my case, the trait works, but when I set a parameter `$exceptTables = ['table1', 'table2']`, they still get truncated whereas they shouldn't.

When using the parameter `$tablesToTruncate = ['table1']`, it works correctly.

I could put all the tables in this second parameter, but it would be cleaner to just specify the few ones I mustn't truncate.

Anyone has seen this before?

Comment: As per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/dusk#:~:text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20may,excluded%20from%20truncation), its `$exceptTables` ( you missed a `s` at the end ). Was that just a type here?

Comment: I just misstyped in my question, I did copy paste from documentation, in the code there is the s :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the `DatabaseTruncation` trait [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/DatabaseTruncation.php#L76-L122), `$exceptTables` should be grouped by connection name as shown, and `$connectionsToTruncate` should be present.

```php
abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use DatabaseTruncation;

    protected $connectionsToTruncate = [
      'mysql_testing'
    ];

    protected $exceptTables = [
        'mysql_testing' => [
            'table1',
            'table2'
        ]
    ];
}
```

I submitted a pull request to Laravel 10 to support an array of table names without the connection key: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/47477

Comment: Oh, I will give it a try asap ! Thank's for the tip

Comment: You're welcome, we are adding E2E tests and had the same issue.   Good luck on your journey!